# removing row in datatables

Tags: jquery, database, datatable

I have a table using the datatable plugin. I am trying to remove a row from it dynamically using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var oTable = $("table#demo-dtable-02").dataTable({"aaSorting": []});

    $(".icon-remove").on('click',function(){
        var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );
        deleted=oTable.fnDeleteRow(anSelected[0] );
      });

              });
```

I get the following error ReferenceError: fnGetSelected is not defined
I tried using (from here: [jQuery Data Tables plugin not removing table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324875/jquery-data-tables-plugin-not-removing-table-row))

```
$(this).parent('tr').remove();
```

This would of course remove the row but will not reset the text in the footer like 
Showing 1 to 10 of 17 entries.
Removing this way is not the best solution to this.

My DOM Code looks like:

```
<?PHP
                                            $count=1;
foreach($ledgers as $row) {?>
    <tr >
    <td><a onClick="viewDetails(<?PHP echo $row['id'];?>)" style="cursor:pointer"><?PHP echo $row['name'];?></a></td>

     <td><?PHP echo $row['email'];?></td>
     <td><?PHP echo $row['contact_number'];?></td>

     <td>
     <i class="icon-remove" rowcount=<?PHP echo $count;?> style="cursor:pointer; margin-right:5px" title="Remove Ledger" id="removeLedgerNow"></i>

    <i class="icon-edit" style="cursor:pointer" title="Edit Ledger" onclick="viewDetails(<?PHP echo $row['id'];?>)"></i>

   </td>
  </tr>
   <?PHP $count++; } ?>
```

Comment.

Comment: Why are you using `.each()`? That's not how you set click events

Comment: see my edit. it doesn't work as well.

Comment: See my answer. It should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated:**

Try this code:

```
 $('.icon-remove').on('click', function () {
   // Get the position of the current data from the node
   var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( $(this).closest('tr').get(0) );
   // Delete the row
   oTable.fnDeleteRow(aPos);
 } );
```

Notes:

1. There is no `fnGetSelected` in the API. It could be a custom function the OP has, but is not produced in the question.
2. `fnGetPosition` is accepts `td`, `th`, or `tr` element
3. `.get(0)` is to break the element out of the jQuery object

Comment: results in this error:  aPos is null. You have used 'this' in fnGetPosition but this in this case is the class (.icon-remove) handler which is just a button in each row. Just guessing :)

Comment: Just for clarity, the `.icon-remove` class i am using is set to the last `td` in each `tr`. How's your DOM?

Comment: See my edit in the question  <i class="icon-remove" rowcount=<?PHP echo $count;?> style="cursor:pointer; margin-right:5px" title="Remove Ledger" id="removeLedgerNow"></i> This line is the one.

Comment: Try using `$(this).closest('tr')` OR `$(this).closest('td')` instead of `this`, and tell me which (if any) works

Comment: How about this? `$(this).closest('td')`. Sorry I don't have a test environment. jsbin and jsfiddle are both mystersiously not working

Comment: its a no again! I wanted to understand one thing. I am declaring oTable as a global variable. Then why the hell the function fnGetSelected( oTable ); not working?

Comment: You want to update those variations here? For someone else who stumbles across this question